# i have created a stored procedure for updating a table named room but checking another table called room_status.iam gettin an error unknown room_s tab

Tags: mysql, sql

```
IF(room_status.check_out<date_in) THEN
 UPDATE room SET  room.status='AVAILABLE';
 ELSE
  UPDATE room SET  room.status='BOOKED' ;
  END IF
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It  does not mention that you need the title to provide the question

Comment: You need to use a `SELECT` query to get the value of `room_status.check_out`.

Comment: `UPDATE room SET  room.status='AVAILABLE';` will change the status for ALL rooms!

Answer (score 0):

You can't access `room_status.check_out` outside a query that selects from the `room_status` table.

If you want to do this in all rows, put the condition inside the `UPDATE` that joins the tables.

```
UPDATE room AS r
JOIN room_status AS rs ON r.id = rs.room_id
SET r.status = IF(rs.check_out < date_in, 'AVAILABLE', 'BOOKED')
```